# Implement "fetch more" in Blazor and C#

Tags: c#, blazor, blazor-server-side

I'm studying blazor.
When page scroll to bottom, I want to fetch more data asynchronously and append to bottom of page.
How can I implement this feature?
Please give me some hint.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: take a look at [BlazorVirtualScrolling](https://github.com/SamProf/BlazorVirtualScrolling)

Comment: @MasLoo this guy is asking about 2+2 and you say look for [defined integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integral)